# Obtener MAC en Django/python

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Quiero obtener la mac de un dispositivo,
estoy importando:

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac


mac = get_mac()
print ('mac...>>>:',mac)
```

Sin embargo traè digitos que no corresponden a una  MAC (00:00:00:00:00:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener tu dirección MAC como la quieres solo necesitas hacer algo adicional, quedando tu código así:

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac

mac = get_mac()
mac = ':'.join(("%012X" % mac)[i:i+2] for i in range(0, 12, 2))
print ('MAC >>>: ', mac)
```

Básicamente lo que haces es convertir ese número que te retorna a hexadecimal y separarlo de 2 en dos añadiendo los `:` correspondientes